# How to upgrade nested dependency log4j version in maven?

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

This is regarding the 0-day exploit found in log4j2 Java logging package
https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/log4j-zero-day/

Below is my code :
pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Alpha7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Alpha5</version>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
     </dependency>
```

Each of above dependency has a inner dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And jboss-logging uses
log4j » log4j   1.2.16
org.apache.logging.log4j » log4j-api 2.11.2

How do I update pom.xml to use org.apache.logging.log4j » log4j-core Version :2.15.0 ?

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put the 2 dependencies (log4j-api and log4j-core) with the new version in your dependencyManagment section in your pom.
Maven will resolve the inner transitive dependencies to this version

Comment: I wish there were more explanations on how to do that exactly.

Comment: Hello, i tried the similar way to upgrade my log4j version, and also added the properties like <log4j2.version>2.17.2</log4j2.version>. Still i see the vulnerability for log4j cve-2019-17571, cve-2022-23305